# How to block firebox/about:addons page in firefox settings?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-addons, blocking

I have been using Blocksite extension for blocking a couple of websites for my productivity. It seems to be working but whenever I feel the urge to use a blocked website,
'Youtube' for example; I simply go to Firefox settings and extensions/add-ons page and simply toggle the Blocksite extension to off.

Is there way I am unable to access the ***extensions/add-ons*** settings and ultimately unable to toggle it off?

Alternatively, you can also let me know if there is an stricter extension for blocking websites (and keywords, if possible) in Firefox (Google chrome also, if needed and extension is not available in Firefox) which makes it impossible to uninstall and toggle it off as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, see the article
[[Firefox Tip] Block About:Config, About:Addons, About:Profiles and About:Support Pages](https://www.askvg.com/firefox-tip-block-about-config-about-addons-about-profiles-and-about-support-pages/):

- Use `regedit` and navigate to the key:

  ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies
  ```
- Create a new key under **Policies** key and set its name as **Mozilla**
- Create another new key under Mozilla key and set its name as **Firefox**
- Now select the **Firefox** key and in the right-side pane
  right-click and select "New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value".
  Set its name as `BlockAboutAddons` and set its value to `1`

[image]

However, as a general remark, there is nothing that you, as administrator
of the computer, can do that you cannot also undo.
The above fix only means that you will need several steps in order to
workaround this limitation.

In the end, only you and your willpower are the true solution.

Comment: Thank you. Immensely helpful.

Comment: Can we use a similar method for Google Chrome as well?

Comment: I don't know of a method to block `chrome://settings/`. You could try putting up a new post for it.